# Using Pandas dataframe with FOR loops

Tags: python, pandas

and thank you for looking.

I am trying my hand at modifying a Python script to download a bunch of data from a website.  I have decided that given the large data that will be used, I am wanting to convert the script to Pandas for this.  I have this code so far.

```
snames = ['Index','Node_ID','Node','Id','Name','Tag','Datatype','Engine']
sensorinfo = pd.read_csv(sensorpath, header = None, names = snames, index_col=['Node', 'Index'])
for j in sensorinfo['Node']:    
     for z in sensorinfo['Index']:

    # create a string for the url of the data
    data_url = "http://www.mywebsite.com/emoncms/feed/data.json?id=" + sensorinfo['Id'] + "&apikey1f8&start=&end=&dp=600"
    print data_url
    # read in the data from emoncms
    sock = urllib.urlopen(data_url)
    data_str = sock.read()
    sock.close

    # data is output as a string so we convert it to a list of lists
    data_list = eval(data_str)
    myfile = open(feed_list['Name'[k]] + ".csv",'wb')

    wr=csv.writer(myfile,quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
```

The first part of the code gives me a very nice table which means I am opening my csv data file and import the information, my question is this:

So I am trying to do this in pseudo code:

```
For node is nodes (4 nodes so far)
 For index in indexes
       data_url = websiteinfo + Id + sampleinformation
      smalldata.read.csv(data_url)
      merge(bigdata, smalldata.no_time_column)
```

This is my first post here, I tried to keep it short but still supply the relevant data.  Let me know if I need to clarify anything.

Answer (score 0):

In your pseudocode, you can do this:

```
dfs = []
For node is nodes (4 nodes so far)
   For index in indexes
      data_url = websiteinfo + Id + sampleinformation
      df = smalldata.read.csv(data_url)
      dfs.append(df)

df = pd.concat(dfs)
```

Comment: because its missing essential steps in his code and he used psuedocode.

Comment: If he gave the full function, I would be happy to write it for him

Comment: I tried to include the steps that I thought would get my point across without bogging down with my WHOLE script.  What essential steps would you like to see?

Comment: to be honest, its not clear what you are trying to do.
does my list solution work for you?